# Can't initialize/start emulator after press F5 without starting emulator device VS 2019/2022

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

If in a new project I start the emulator device and next press F5 the project is showed in the device correctly, but if I miss step one and directly press F5 it returns the error of the tittle and at that point doesn't matter what I do that I keep getting the same error message. I removed temporary files, clean the project, build, re-build, reopen Visual Studio,... like something is broken and unfixeable. I'm using VS 2019 and JDK and SDK are updated and this happen in a new PC with Xamarin just installed.

[image: Visual Studio Output]

[image: Emulator Configuration]

Comment: In general, we start the emulator first, and deploy our app to our emulator.  You can try this step. If the problem persist, you can try to remove the emulator and create a new one.

Comment: I did and the problem persist, however it works if I plug an Android device, but debugging is slower.

Comment: You can try to repair your visual studio and try again.  For more, check: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: I even installed VS 2022 in a new machine and after run the virtual emulator I get "Device error: Could not get emulator name after starting AVD pixel_5_-_api_30", for a just created new emulator.

Comment: You can recheck if you have set up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android correctly.

Comment: I have installed and updated Android SDK, Android SDK Build Tools and Android Emulator, that is what you mean?

Comment: Could you please post the  relative screenshots here?

Comment: Done. I had to enable fastColdBoot but even so the output indicates that can't start emulator and shows a black screen.